# Should do vs should be doing

Tags: meaning, difference

What's the difference between:

> *What should we be doing if <strike>the</strike> inflation goes up?*

and

> *What should we do if inflation goes up?*

Comment: I'd always suggest using the simpler of possible alternative verb forms in any case. Superficially there doesn't seem to be anything obviously "grammatically incorrect" about using the continuous form (#1) here, and I certainly don't think many native speakers would unhesitatingly rule it out. But on closer consideration I don't think it really works very well anyway. We often use Present Continuous to reference future acts *(I am going to London tomorrow)*, but if it's a *conditional, hypothetical* future we tend to be more explicit *(I will go to London tomorrow if you come with me)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- What **should we be doing if** inflation goes up?

The progressive form here indicates an increased concern about the problem. The progressive makes the action more immediate to perception.

I wouldn't suggest this construction to refer to *a conditional, hypothetical future.*

However, it can be used in such examples:

- "What **should we be doing when** Mary comes tomorrow?"
- "We **should be collecting** cherry in the garden."

The second fits in here best:

- What **should we do if** inflation goes up? *(What should we do in the future if hypothetically the inflation goes up?)*

The first would fit in good enough if it were constructed this way:

- What **should we be doing if we want** the inflation not to go up? *(What are we doing wrong now and what should we do instead?)*

Compared to:

- What **should we do if we want** the inflation not to go up? *(What measures should be taken?)*